# Некорректное получение ссылки

Tags: java, android

Есть диалог, в котором реализован метод получения ID-шника ссылки

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ОК", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String string = input.getText().toString();
            useLinkInput(string);
        }
```

А вот собственно и сам метод получения ID:

```
private void useLinkInput(String input) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(input);
    String videoID = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
    url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID +"/0.jpg";
    Log.d("url",url);
}
```

В логи выводит ссылку, которую вводит пользователь, но ссылка не отображается:

```
D/url: http://img.youtube.com/vi/null/0.jpg
```

Comment: а что вы передаете в `String input`? Я знаю, что это должна быть ссылка, которую пользователь вводит в диалоге, но что именно вводите вы?

Comment: @metalurgus скопировал/вставил ссылку из ютуба или я не понял вопроса.

Comment: Вы поняли вопрос. Такого вида ссылка: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxlP9esCFzY`?

Comment: Выведите еще в самом начале в лог те, что вы передали в параметр метода: `Log.d("input",input);`. Возможно, вы как-то не правильно передаете параметр

Comment: @metalurgus  ну не совсем, но тоже с ютуба. Добавил лог, вывело следующее D/input: https://youtu.be/miVRaoR_8xQ

Comment: @Inkognito возможно Split Вам поможет, чтобы отобразить корректно ссылку.

Comment: Так это же очевидно, в ссылке нет параметра `v`, который вы пытаетесь получить `String videoID = uri.getQueryParameter("v");`. Это у вас сокращенная ссылка. А параметр есть только в полной вида `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxlP9esCFzY`. В сокращенной ссылке ID видео находится после слеша - `miVRaoR_8xQ`. Для сокращенной ссылки нужно отбросить все, что находится до слеша, и сам слеш.

Comment: @metalurgus uri.getQueryParameter(""); удалил v, но думаю дело не в этом. Не подскажете как правильно нужно написать ?

Comment: давайте вы сами это сделаете, а я подскажу просто. Забудьте про ту строку, что у вас уже написана в коде: `uri.getQueryParameter("");`. Вам надо из `youtu.be/miVRaoR_8xQ` сделать `miVRaoR_8xQ`. Подумайте, как это сделать. Погуглите...

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам всё же понадобиться выводить не только ссылки, которые в вопросе, но и их "короткие" версии(short link), то просто видоизмените Ваш код следующим образом:

```
private void useLinkInput(String input) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(input);
    String videoID = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(videoID)) {
        String[] str = input.split("/");
        videoID = str[str.length - 1];
    }
    url = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/0.jpg";
    Log.d("url", url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция получения video ID для youtube по любым (so far) ссылкам:

```
public static String getYoutubeId(String url) {
    String id = "";
    String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed/|youtu.be/|/v/|/e/|watch\\?v%3D|watch\\?feature=player_embedded&v=|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%\u200C\u200B2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#&\\?\\n]*";

    Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url); 
    if (matcher.find()) {
        id = matcher.group();
    }
    return id;
}
```